# Literature to understand the components of Temporal Fusion Transformer

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, transformers, attention, temporal-fusion-transformer

I'm currently reading the paper *Temporal Fusion Transformers for Interpretable Multi-horizon Time Series Forecasting*: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.09363v3

However, I had to stop at page 7/8, which contains the different pieces of the TFT, because I lack the knowledge of most of the pieces mentioned there. Thus, my following questions are:

1.) **What are the different components I have to understand, in order to understand how the TFT works?** So far I got: LSTM (and Gates), Transformers (with Encoders/Decoders), and Multi-Headed-Attention-Blocks, are there more parts I have to understand the TFT, e.g. what about the GRN or Dense?

2.) **Do you know of any literature that explains these components in terms of time-series AND are not that math-heavy?**
I normally learn the maths from an example much better.
So far, I read through a few blogs, looked some tutorials or vids, even a video about the paper itself, but they do not focus so strong on the individual components. Furthermore, nearly every tutorial explains parts of the TFT as a problem of speech-translation for example, and not as a time-series problem.

Although I did some transfer to time-series. I have no further literature to crossvalidate my thoughts to.

So far I read/viewed:

- Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) and Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM)
  by Brandon Rohrer:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCUNPb-5EYI
- Short intro to RNN and then LSTM: https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/
- Temporal Fusion Transformers for Interpretable Multi-horizon Time Series Forecasting by Arvid Kingl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7O4VqRf8s4&t=1106s
- Transformer Neural Networks by CodeEmporium: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQQlZhbC5ps

All the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should understand why Temporal Fusion Transformer(TFT) is such an awesome model.

The biggest advantages of TFT are **versatility** and **interpretability**. In other words, the model works with multiple time series, with all sorts of inputs (even categorical variables!). Also, it is not a black-box model: With attention weights you can can find which features are important, as well as the dominant seasonal patterns in your dataset! How cool is that?

I recommend reading this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/temporal-fusion-transformer-googles-model-for-interpretable-time-series-forecasting-5aa17beb621). It explains in depth the different components of TFT and how they work together. A slightly difficult concept to grasp in case you are not familiar with is the **Attention** mechanism. Besides, TFT is a Transformer-based model so it uses attention (with some extra perks). If you hear the term attention for the first time (in the context of deep learning), take a look [here](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) - this is the best source on the internet that explains attention, plus it uses illustrations!

(Disclaimer: I am the author of the first article)